# My amazon beanstalk instance is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using eclipse to deploy java RESTful web project in amazon elastic beanstalk and it is successfully deployed. Snapshot of my Beanstalk dashboard is:

[image: here].

When I try to access the http://event-api.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/ URL, it shows 404 error. Why am I getting this 404 error?

I did not change web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>EventMngmtApi</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

     <init-param>
      <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
      <param-value>com.vasithwam.users,com.vasithwam.event</param-value>

    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```